# updating play services location from 8.4.0 to 9.8.0

Tags: android

hello i am having problem when updating my

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
to
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
```

the ff imports could not be found

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
```

so when i use this class it says cannot resolve symbol, the Place Class

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
```

anyone have some fix for this? thanks please

Answer (score 1):

In recent update they dispatched some classes in another dependencies.

PlacePicker is now in 
`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0"`